# Would like to add new second hard drive with ubuntu but keep a shared portion for Windows 11 (with Veracypt full disk) on it

Tags: windows

I currently have a Windows 11 desktop with Veracrypt whole disk encryption.

I have installed a second 1 TB drive and would like to install ubuntu on 300 GB and then keep the other 700 GB as a shared space accessible by both Windows and Ubuntu (if possible).  If not, only with Windows.

Any writeups/video to point me to?  Will Veracrypt cause a problem?

Newbie here (obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Use Gnome-disk utility that is in your standard apps (use the search field if you have to, string: "disks")

Create with the utility-tool a partition on your, extra, 1TB drive of 300Gb like you have said. Set that partition to ext4 what Ubuntu really likes.
The rest of the remaining partition, being the remaining 700Gb, you format this to NTFS, Windows will see it and add it as an extra space for data. As for your Veracrypt of Windows you'll have to dig into that one, as this is not Linux at all. Remember if you install Ubuntu, you can use on that an encryption as well (protected with a password) during installation.

But the proceedings are really easy : run a LIVE-session and use Gnome disks or, if you are familiar with tech tools, Gparted that is in the Live session offered. So make a bootable stick, boot the stick, and choose first TRY UBUNTU for running the LIVE-session and thus format the extra 1Tb drive. Remember all is based on wysiwyg.

Comment: I went ahead and installed ubuntu on the secondary drive, but the boot menu only shows the windows boot when pressing F12.  I guess that makes sense, as bios would not know that there is a os on the second hard drive.  I did not chose the "install along windows" option, but chose the standalone option.  I was afraid there would be issues with "install along windows" and veracypt boot up which asks for the whole system encryption password.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to install of course GRUB on the primary drive, where your windows is now.

Comment: Is it possible to install Grub to a thumbdrive?  when I hit F12 it will get me the option to boot from the thumb drive.  This way, when I want to use Linux, I can insert the thumb drive and then have that boot from the second drive?  Not elegant, but it would make me feel better not messing with the veracrypt'ed drive.  How would I go about doing that?  I would still like to use ubuntu installed on the 2nd hard drive, but just use the thumb drive to get it started.